# Print txt. file using JOptionpane

Tags: file, joptionpane

I created a txt. file (vector [14]) , it's a list of 14 countries that I need to print (all of them) using JOptionPane or similiar, but all appers to me is the first country. Someone can help me please?
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

```
    int cont=0;
    BufferedReader fr= new BufferedReader (new FileReader("paises.txt")) ;
    String destino= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o seu país de destino:");
    String busca = destino;
    try {
        while (fr.ready()) {
            String linha= fr.readLine();
            if(linha.equals(busca)) {
              cont =1; 
            }
        }
    fr.close();
    if (cont==1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"OK!","Opção Destinos",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE) ;
    } else {
        int res =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Destino não encontrado, gostaria de visualizar todos os países que fazem parte da nossa rota?","Ops!!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (res==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {                            
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("paises.txt"));
        String pp = inFile.nextLine();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,pp, "Próxima Parada", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

               }
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println ("ERRO");

    }
```

}
}